# I'm trying to create a simple neural network using ML.NET with regression which returns the specified number, but it returns a different number

Tags: c#, .net, machine-learning, ml.net

I learn ML.NET library. In general, I use regression trainers in my projects.

I have this code which must return number, which given to model:

```
    class Program
    {
        static Input[] trainData;

        static void CreateData(int count = 100)
        {
            trainData = new Input[count];

            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
            {
                trainData[i] = new Input { Column1 = i, Result = i };
            }
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateData();
            var mlContext = new MLContext();

            var dataView = mlContext.Data.LoadFromEnumerable(trainData);
            var pipeline = mlContext.Transforms.CopyColumns("Label", "Result")
                .Append(mlContext.Transforms.Concatenate("Features", "Column1"))
                .Append(mlContext.Regression.Trainers.Sdca()); 

            var model = pipeline.Fit(dataView);

            var predictor = mlContext.Model.CreatePredictionEngine<Input, Output>(model);
            var prediction = predictor.Predict(new Input { Column1 = 178, Result = 0});

            Console.WriteLine(prediction.Result);
            Console.Beep(500, 100);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    class Input
    {
        public float Column1;

        public float Result;
    }
    class Output
    {
        [ColumnName("Score")]
        public float Result;
    }
```

That's all, but it returns 173, and with FastTree() trainer my predictor return 94.
What's wrong?

Comment: Try getting metrics on it using the `mlContext.Regression.Evaluate` method and see what the R^2 value is. The closer to 1 it is indicates how good the model is.

Comment: Also, try adding more data. That would help the model learn the patterns in the data.

Comment: @Jon, thanks for your answer.the value of RSquared is approximately 0.97-0.99. But than more number i give to it, than greater value of expression "expected-actual". With count=100 and Column1 = 1 I get 1.01. With count = 10000 and Column1 = 1 I get 1.02. With count = 100 and Column1 = 180 I get 165,3. With count = 10000 and Column1 = 180 I get 154.08. I apologize for the unclear text